# Delay batch of observables with RxJS

Tags: rxjs, delay

I perform http requests to my db and have noticed that if I send all the requests at once, some of them will get a timeout errors. I'd like to add a delay between calls so the server doesn't get overloaded. I'm trying to find the RxJS solution to this problem and don't want to add a `setTimeout`.

Here is what I currently do:

```
let observables = [];
for(let int = 0; int < 10000; int++){
   observables.push(new Observable((observer) => {
      db.add(doc[int], (err, result)=>{
         observer.next();
         observer.complete();
      })
   }))
}

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
   data => {
   },
   error => {
      console.log(error);
   },
   () => {
      db.close();
   }
);
```

Comment: You could zip your observable with a timer observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed achieve this with Rxjs quite nicely. You'll need higher order observables, which means you'll emit an observable into an observable, and the higher order observable will flatten this out for you.

The nice thing about this approach is that you can easily run X requests in // without having to manage the pool of requests yourself.

Here's the working code:

```
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { mergeAll, take, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

// this is just a mock to demonstrate how it'd behave if the API was
// taking 2s to reply for a call
const mockDbAddHtppCall = (id, cb) =>
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, `some result for call "${id}"`);
  }, 2000);

// I have no idea what your response type looks like so I'm assigning
// any but of course you should have your own type instead of this
type YourRequestType = any;

const NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_FETCH = 10;

const calls$$ = new Subject<Observable<YourRequestType>>();

calls$$
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(3),
    take(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_FETCH),
    tap({ complete: () => console.log(`All calls are done`) })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

for (let id = 0; id < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_FETCH; id++) {
  calls$$.next(
    new Observable(observer => {
      console.log(`Starting a request for ID "${id}""`);
      mockDbAddHtppCall(id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          observer.error(err);
        } else {
          observer.next(result);
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    })
  );
}
```

**And a live demo on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z1x5m9**

Please open the console of your browser and note that the console log showing when a call is being triggered starts straight away for 3 of them, and then wait for 1 to finish before picking up another one.

Comment: BTW this is exactly what I want but I need to know when they are all done... I can't track the last request since the order might be different at the response (requests don't have a consistent duration)

Comment: Oh right. Well you know the number of items you're looping on, so you can simply add a `take(numberOfItems)`

Comment: I've edited the code above and the stackblitz to display a message when all the calls are done

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use an initial `timer` to trigger the http calls. e.g.

`timer(delayTime).pipe(combineLatest(()=>sendHttpRequest()));`

This would only trigger the `sendHttpRequest()` method after the timer observable had completed.

So with your solution. You could do the following...

```
   observables.push(
     timer(delay + int).pipe(combineLatest(new Observable((observer) => {
      db.add(doc[int], (err, result)=>{
         observer.next();
         observer.complete();
      }))
   }))
```

Where delay could probably start off at 0 and you could increase it using the `int` index of your loop by some margin.

Timer docs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer

Combine latest docs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: This is not ideal as you'd have all the observables running at the same time, just waiting a bit for a timeout to happen before triggering the HTTP call. Instead you can create a list of cold observables that you push into an observable and then use a higher order observable to flatten that. The main advantage being that only 3 observables will be subscribed at the same time. I've made an answer to explain that a bit more in detail and give an example

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, each observable here adds a delay onto each call. So e.g. you'd get timer(1), timer(2), timer(3)... etc. which would give you your n observables which would fire one millisecond after the other. I thought the question asked to fire observables with delays between them. I'm sure some wires must  have been crossed here. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

#### `merge` with concurrent value:

`mergeAll` and `mergeMap` both allow you to define the max number of subscribed observables. `mergeAll(1)`/`mergeMap(LAMBDA, 1)` is basically `concatAll()`/`concatMap(LAMBDA)`.

`merge` is basically just the static `mergeAll`

Here's how you might use that:

```
let observables = [...Array(10000).keys()].map(intV => 
  new Observable(observer => {
    db.add(doc[intV], (err, result) => {
      observer.next();
      observer.complete();
    });
  })
);

const MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10;

merge(...observables, MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS).subscribe({
   next: data => {},
   error: err => console.log(err),
   complete: () => db.close()
});
```

---

Of note: This doesn't batch your calls, but it should solve the problem described and it **may** be a bit faster than batching as well.

---

#### `mergeMap` with concurrent value:

Perhaps a slightly more RxJS way using `range` and `mergeMap`

```
const MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10;

range(0, 10000).pipe(
  mergeMap(intV => 
    new Observable(observer => {
      db.add(doc[intV], (err, result) => {
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
      });
    }),
    MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS
  )
).subscribe({
   next: data => {},
   error: err => console.log(err),
   complete: () => db.close()
});
```